# Streaming into Dataflow from Datastore?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-dataflow

Is it possible to use the Datastore as an input on a streaming basis? I.e. any time an entity is saved to the datastore it streams that to a dataflow project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently we do not stream out of Datastore automatically, but I've made a note of your interest in it. One approach you can consider is to monitor any relevant source from a App Engine and publish its contents to PubSub.

Comment: Using cursors and time stamps is a cost effective way to monitor Datastore for new/changed records. I can provide more details if this is of interest. You'd need the "monitoring" application to query periodically.